# Android : SQL Server Checking login details programmatically

Tags: android, sql-server, kotlin, mssql-jdbc

I have a price checker app that the user want to insert it's server details from a setting page (ip, user and pass).

They asked to have the app notify them if the connection was successful or was the details incorrect once they input the data into the app / Pad, that is used as a price checker.

The server is SQL Server and I have the `net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.4` driver implemented (they have an old 4.4 Android)

Comment: @dale-k thank you for the corrections. I found 2 more typos and corrected them.. so kind of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the policy preferences for the connection to check the details instead of login

instead of `val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()` 
i made it as below.

```
    fun checkConnection(
        url: String,
        user: String,
        pass: String,
    ): Boolean{
        try {
            val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().build() <--
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
            Class.forName(cls) // "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass)
            return true
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace() <-- you can take this message to display it on UI or you can write your own.
            return false
        }
    }
```